# jQuery toggle() and only copy visible text without using remove()

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

Here's my code:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <span class="togglers complete">
        <a class="toggler" href="#" title="change" style="display: none;">I'm sending</a>
        <span class="divider" style="display: none;">|</span>
        <a class="toggler selected" href="#" title="change">We're sending</a>
        <span class="divider" style="display: none;">|</span>
        <a class="toggler" href="#" title="change" style="display: none;">I've sent</a>
        <span class="divider" style="display: none;">|</span>
         <a class="toggler" href="#" title="change" style="display: none;">We've sent</a>
    </span>
    you a message with that information so let me know if you don't receive it.
</div>
```

I'm trying to only get the .toggler that is visible on the screen.  I have a button set up so when I click it, it logs the sentence in the console to test. I started off with:

```
$(this).siblings(".post-content").find(':hidden').remove().end().text().replace(/\s+/g, " ")
```

which worked, until I tried clicking the .toggler after I clicked the button, but since they had been removed they don't show up.

So I tried something like this:

```
console.log($(this).siblings(".post-content").find().not(':hidden').end().text().replace(/\s+/g, " "))
```

because it comes back null

To add to the complications they also have `visiblity:visible` applied to all of them because they're in a pop up module (Foundation's reveal) and inherits the style so I can't do

```
$(this).siblings(".post-content").not(':hidden').end().text().replace(/\s+/g, " ")
```

because it shows everything.

I'm trying to get something along the lines of if it's not `display:none` then show it.  So ideally, in this example, I'd end up with:

We're sending you a message with that information so let me know if you don't receive it.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fletchling/kMshk/20/) with the original line of code.

Comment: Instead of using `.remove()` couldn't you toggle a class like `.toggleClass('hide')` and add in your CSS `.hide { display: none; }`?

Comment: What about using a cloned element: http://jsfiddle.net/kMshk/21/

Comment: @A.Wolff - Yes! This is my favorite. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what if you added a class called "exclude" to each item and then called toggle on the children of your parent div?

$(".post-content").children(":not(.exclude)").toggle();